# Common Base Amplifier - Hybrid-Pi vs. T Model

Tags: bjt

I have a common base amplifier with a source resistance and a load resistor.  I am trying to solve for the system gain including the source resistor with both the hybrid-pi and T model but seem to be getting different answers.

When solving the hybrid-pi model for Vbe by looking at the currents at the emitter I end up with an extra gm term due to the voltage controlled current source.  I do not get this term when I solve for the same circuit with the T-model.  Any help?  Its probably something simple I am missing.

Comment: You need to show your circuit and specify exactly what "gain" is in your context.  Is it a voltage ratio?  Current ratio?  Power ratio?  Ratio of what to what exactly.  Without proper units and definitions this is just handwaving, not engineering.

Answer (score 1):

Without the equations you get it's hard to know exactly what's going on, but you wouldn't expect to get a "gm" term when you solve for the gain T model, as the model consists of a current controlled current source Beta*ib in series with the dynamic emitter resistance.  The two are related, however, as Beta*ib = (Beta/r_pi)*v_pi = gm*v_pi.  For the T model of a common base amplifier with source resistance Rs and load resistance RL, one should get the gain as being (alpha*RL)/(Rs + Re), with Re being the dynamic emitter resistance.

Comment: That is the gain I get for the T model.  For the hybrid-Pi model I get: Vo/Vi = (gm*Rl*Rpi) / (gm * Rs * Rpi + Rs + Rpi).  The difference is that gm term on the bottom when the equation is simplified down.

That extra term comes from when I solve for the currents coming into and out of the emitter.  As the base is grounded Ve determines Vbe so I get:
Ve/Rpi = gm(-Ve) + (Vs-Ve)/Rs

The gm(-Ve) term propagates through and causes the gm * Rs * Rpi difference in the final answer.

Thanks.